# Extracting data from a web page to Excel sheet

Tags: asp.net, excel, vba, web

How can I extract information from a web page into an Excel sheet?

The website is https://www.proudlysa.co.za/members.php and I would like to extract all the companies listed there and all their respective information.

Comment: @noyanc Ok I am waiting and thanks

Comment: Sorry about the wait. Posted an answer.

Comment: @noyanc Whether you're writing an answer or not has no bearing on the question's validity. If it should be closed, it should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

The process you're referring to is called web scraping, and there are several VBA tutorials out there for you to try.

Alternatively, you can always try
[image]
<sub>(source: [netdna-ssl.com](https://analystcave-analystcave.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/powerQuery_FromWeb.png))</sub>

Answer (score -1):

I tried creating something to grab for all pages. But ran of time and had bugs. This should help you a little. You will have to do this on all 112 pages.

Using chrome go to the page

type `javascript:` in the url then paste the code below. it should extra what you need. then you will have to just copy and paste it in to excel.

```
var list = $(document).find(".pricing-list");
var csv ="";
for (i = 0; list.length > i;i++) {
    var dataTags = list[i].getElementsByTagName('li');
    var dataArr = [];
    for (j = 0; dataTags.length > j;j++) {
        dataArr.push(dataTags[j].innerText.trim());

    }
    csv += dataArr.join(', ') + "<br>";
}
```

you will get something like this

[image]

**EDITTED**

use this instead will automatically download each page as csv then you can just combine them after somehow.

**Make sure to type `javascript:` in url before pasting and pressing enter**

**Also works with chrome, not sure about other browsers. i dont use them much**

```
var list = $(document).find(".pricing-list");
var csv ="data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
for (i = 0; list.length > i;i++) {
    var dataTags = list[i].getElementsByTagName('li');
    var dataArr = [];
    for (j = 0; dataTags.length > j;j++) {
        dataArr.push(dataTags[j].innerText.trim());

    }
    csv += dataArr.join(', ') + "\n";
}
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = ""+ encodeURI(csv);
a.download = "data.csv";
a.click();
```